# Google Analytics 4 (GA4): How to show the URL (www.domain.com/page) in Page Path, not the URI (/page)?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Currently, our reports in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) show the URI (/page) under the "Page Page" dimension.

We track multiple subdomains ([www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), tribe.domain.com, etc) with the same GA4 property, so we want the "Page Page" to show the URL ([www.domain.com/page](http://www.domain.com/page)).

Any ideas where/how to set this up?

Comment: I've just answered a similar question in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218548/1920145

Answer (score 1):

The page_view event contains the page_location parameter which contains the full url.

[Screen Shot of page_location parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOmWe.png)

Comment: Could you explain more?